# Reading high voltage output NPN proximity sensor with Ardunio YUN

Tags: npn, pullup, proximity-sensor

I have a NPN proximity sensor with rating voltage 6-36 VDC.
(https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07SD9VYDH/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

To power it up, I use a 24 VDC power supply and buck converter to step down the voltage to 9 VDC.

When the sensor is idle, the reading voltage shown by a multi-meter is the voltage supplied by power supply (9 VDC).

**The problem is input PIN Arduino operates at 5 VDC**. So I need to check whether this sensor works with pull-up resistor before connecting it to the Arduino.

Below is the wiring that I made [image]

following the schematic from here [image] Theortically speaking the measurement of output voltage should be equal to pull-up voltage which is 5 VDC from Arduino. However, the measurement that I got was 7.5 VDC.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the wiring? or with the schematic?

Many thanks

Comment: Could the sensor have an *internal 10k pullup resistor*? You might be able to measure its resistance (if it is present) with a multimeter between Black & Brown sensor wires. Measure resistance twice: swapping red & blk meter leads. Both measurements should be similar. If they're not, a diode or transistor junction invalidates the measurement. Ideally, an open-collector NPN transistor (black wire) should measure very high resistance to brown wire. Measure with sensor connected to nothing else.

Comment: Hi @glen_geek, when I connect brown to red multi-meter and black to black multi-meter, the resistance is nearly 4 M ohm. But, it returns zero when I swap them. does it mean it's an open-collector NPN sensor? also when I measure black to blue with resistor connected the voltage is pulled down to the ground

Comment: Seems your NPN is properly open-collector. And wiring looks OK. Does a 9V battery to sensor yield the same strange +7.5V? Am suspecting a problem with ground.

Comment: Nope. I am using a power supply stepped down to 9V. the sensor returns the same voltage as supply voltage when measuring directly from black to blue. brown to black is zero when sensor is idle, but brown to black is 9V when sensor is activated.

Comment: So I found some folks hook up directly the open collector NPN signal to the input PIN Arduino with internal pull-up resistor without frying their Arduino. But, I chose to use Optocoupler PC817 at the end since my pull-resistor circuit does not work out as I expect for my proximity sensor and I don't want to risk burning my Arduino. In case, anybody comes across the same issue, Optocoupler could be an alternative.

Comment: @deduu I just dropped by for the first time to see this. I probably would NOT have bothered with the buck converter, since the device is already supposed to work with the 24 V supply you already had available. (From what I read in your question.) I'd then worry about adapting a circuit between the black wire output (vs blue reference) and the I/O pin. I just don't see a need to complicate things by adding a buck converter. Is everything working fine with the transducer??